# how to get click location on bing map 6.3

Tags: javascript, onclick, bing-maps

I try to naviguate on bing map 6.3 using ipad but it's not working. I think about center bing map on each click with the lat and lang of the clicked position, how i get this position? I find the solution for v **7.0** but not for **6.3**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if I would **highly recommend to use the v7** of the AJAX control for a new starting project, here is the solution that will fits your needs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
   <title></title>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<script charset="UTF-8" type="text/javascript" src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=6.3&mkt=en-us">
</script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    var map = null;

    function GetMap()
    {
        map = new VEMap('myMap');
        map.LoadMap();

        map.AttachEvent("onclick", function(e) {
            var pixel = new VEPixel(e.mapX, e.mapY);
            var latLong = map.PixelToLatLong(pixel);

            alert(latLong.Latitude + ' ' + latLong.Longitude);
        });
        map.AttachEvent("ondoubleclick", MouseHandler);
    }
   </script>


  </head>
  <body onload="GetMap();">
   <div id='myMap' style="position:relative; width:600px; height:400px;"></div>   
  </body>
</html>
```

You can get the documentation of v6.3 here:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17945